# Java android a.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.os.Parcel.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

My app crash on one device in logs I see only this . In logs I don't see which line of codes cause of this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.os.Parcel.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at android.os.Parcel.nativeDestroy(Parcel.java)
       at android.os.Parcel.destroy(Parcel.java:2277)
       at android.os.Parcel.finalize(Parcel.java:2290)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

#0. Crashed: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at android.os.Parcel.nativeDestroy(Parcel.java)
       at android.os.Parcel.destroy(Parcel.java:2277)
       at android.os.Parcel.finalize(Parcel.java:2290)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

#1. hwuiTask1
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
```